# #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'nombre, apellidoP, apellidoM,fecha,sexo,numIdentidad,direccion'

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

estoy ocupando mysql, php y wamp, pero cuando trato de ingresar datos a mi base de datos me marca este error **#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'nombre, apellidoP, apellidoM,fecha,sexo,numIdentidad,direccion'**, claro con los datos propios del usuario, sin embargo no tengo idea de que podría ser.

La instrucción completa que escribí es la siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO `alumnosnuevoingreso`
(`id`, `boleta`, `nombre`, `aPaterno`, `aMaterno`, `fecha`, `sexo`, 
 `curp`, `calleNo`, `colonia`, `codigoPostal`, `telefonoF`, `telefonoC`, 
 `email`, `escuela`, `nombreEscuela`, `entidadFederativa`, `promedio`, 
 `opcion`) 
VALUES (201676000,Patricio , Lascurain, Corcuera, 1997/12/08, f, 
        MOYU789654DERTTR78, Calle falsa 1, Colonia falsa, 07550, 
        5057112503, 5064705507, correo@falso.com, CET 1, no aplica, 
        Ciudad de México, 8.42, 1ra. Opcion)
```

Alguien que me ayude, por favor

Comment: Las cadenas de texto en el apartado values van entre comillas, si lo tienes así? o se las quiaste al momento de copiar la query aqui

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si estas respuestas han aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarlas para que también puedan ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO  nombre tabla  (Nombre ,Apellido,Contraseña , telefono, direccion)  
VALUES ("Brayan" , "Cruz","1234" , "7722102" , "Cr 7 Miami" );
```

debes evitar las comillas es un poco mas complicado notar el error.

Comment: Evitar las comillas o usar las comillas?

Comment: Pues al inicio de la sentencia en los valores se pueden usar ...

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
INSERT INTO `alumnosnuevoingreso`
(`id`, `boleta`, `nombre`, `aPaterno`, `aMaterno`, `fecha`, `sexo`, 
 `curp`, `calleNo`, `colonia`, `codigoPostal`, `telefonoF`, `telefonoC`, 
 `email`, `escuela`, `nombreEscuela`, `entidadFederativa`, `promedio`, 
 `opcion`) 
VALUES ('201676000','Patricio ','Lascurain','Corcuera','1997/12/08','f', 
        'MOYU789654DERTTR78','Calle falsa 1','Colonia falsa','07550',
        '5057112503','5064705507','correo@falso.com','CET 1','no aplica',
        'Ciudad de México','8.42','1ra. Opcion');
```

En los campos se pueden usar acentos graves y, en los datos, se deben usar comillas dobles o simples. Si en PHP usas unas, en SQL las otras.